# Removing duplicate items in a vector of objects

Tags: vector, duplicates, unique, erase

I have a class CPerson

```
class CPerson
{
private:
    string name;
    string egn;
public:
    CPerson() {};
    CPerson(string getname, string getegn)
    {
        name = getname;
        egn = getegn;
    }
    bool operator < (const CPerson &obj)
    {
        if (egn < obj.egn)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
    bool operator == (const CPerson &obj)
    {
        if (egn == obj.egn)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
```

Then I have a second class CCity which has a vector with CPerson objects.

```
class CCity
{
public:
    string city_name;
    vector <CPerson> people;
public:
    CCity() {};
    CCity(string filename)
    {
        string name, egn;
        ifstream file(filename);
        file >> city_name;
        while (file >> name >> egn)
        {
            people.push_back(CPerson(name,egn));
        }
    }
    void remove_duplicates()
    {
        sort(people.begin(), people.end());
        people.erase(unique(people.begin(), people.end()-1));
    }
};
```

I have already overloaded == and < which should be neccessary but when I use the remove_duplicates function the duplicates are still there after I check the vector contents. Here is the contents of the file I use in the CCity constructor:

```
Varna
EGN0000001 a
EGN0000001 b
EGN0000002 c
EGN0000003 d
EGN0000004 e
EGN0000004 f
EGN0000005 g
EGN0000006 h
EGN0000001 i
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was that I was inserting the what was supposed to be the egn into name and the name in the egn.
This:

```
CCity(string filename)
{
    string name, egn;
    ifstream file(filename);
    file >> city_name;
    while (file >> name >> egn)
    {
        people.push_back(CPerson(name,egn));
    }
}
```

Should be this:

```
CCity(string filename)
{
    string name, egn;
    ifstream file(filename);
    file >> city_name;
    while (file >> egn>> name)
    {
        people.push_back(CPerson(name,egn));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please, refer to this [link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/unique/). I think what you're doing is erasing the last unique element.
As an answer, I hope this code will work:

```
void remove_duplicates()
{
    sort(people.begin(), people.end());
    vector<int>::iterator it = unique(people.begin(), people.end());
    people.resize( std::distance(myvector.begin(),it));
}
```

I hope that helps you

Comment: Yeah, I am removing the last unique element. But your code has errors when copy pasted in mine.

Comment: @duerdak The last line of my code sample contains `myvector` which is a placeholder for `people` vector. Sorry for inconvenience.